# How to get custom messages when you use response.getStatusText()

Tags: spring, http, resttemplate

`HttpClientErrorException` always produces the following result for me:

`HttpClientErrorException: 400 null`

... and the null part is what worries me. Shouldn't this be the place where the message of the server-side exception is supposed to be?

I checked the source code of the HTTP client to see where the client-side exception is thrown. It looks like this:

`throw new HttpClientErrorException(statusCode, response.getStatusText(), response.getHeaders(), getResponseBody(response), getCharset(response));`

Debugging this call revealed that `response.getStatusText()` is null in my case.

My question is: How do you design your ResponseEntity on the server-side such that the HTTP client finds the server-side exception message in response.getStatusText() instead of null?

Here is my Exception

```
 @ExceptionHandler({ MyCustomException.class })
 public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(final HttpServletRequest 
 req, final MyCustomException e) {
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.set("Content-type", "text/plain");
 String body = e.toString();
 return new ResponseEntity<>(body, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

}